# Hibernate createSQLQuery get sql count

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, inheritance, derby

I'm trying to get a sql count as followed

```
            "select c1.id, count(c2.*) "
            + "from Category c1 "
            + "left join Category c2 on c2.parentCategoryId = c1.id "
            + "where c1.id in (" + questions + ") "
            + "group by c1.id");
```

However I'm getting the following sql exception

Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Syntax error: Encountered "*" at line 1, column 24.
        at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)

Could someone help me to get this query working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you replace this:

```
"select c1.id, count(c2.*) "
```

By this?:

```
"select c1.id, count(c2.id) "
```